# Using an image created with css3 as background for a button?

Tags: image, css, button, background, drawing

Is there a way to create an image in css3 (in my case a magnifying glass, e.g. with `.picture` and `.picture:after`) that goes into the button of a search form? I know it is easily done with a background image but I wanna know if you could do that using plain css3, too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
.picture{
    background-image: url(mybg.png);
}
```

use the [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) property

Comment: yeah, I've written that I know it's can be easily done like that... but my question was if you can also do that using pure css3. Because I can draw pictures using css3, and a magnifier is actually quite easy to create. But how would I put that magnifier that I made with css3 as a background? I mean, is that even possible?